# Angular2 - Load binary image data asynchronously inside ngFor

Tags: image, asynchronous, angular, binary, observable

I'm trying to load some images using node's fs module. I have it working on a single image but what is the correct way to do this inside an ngFor loop?

Currently I have:

```
<div *ngFor="let job of getJobs() | async">
   <img src={{readImageFile(job.thumbUrl)}}>
</div>
```

getJobs() returns an observable from my service.

readImageFile() calls a Meteor server-side method which loads the image data using fs and returns it asynchronously:

```
  readImageFile(url) {
    if (url) {
      this.call('readImageFile', url, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log('read image file success');
          return "data:image/jpg;base64," + res;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work.. So what is the correct method for asynchronously loading data inside an ngFor loop?

**update**

I tried with `readImageFile(url) | async`

```
readImageFile: function(url) { 
  var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'); 
  var myFuture = new Future(); 
  fs.readFile(String(url), 
  function read(error, result) { 
    if(error){ 
      myFuture.throw(error); 
    } else { 
      myFuture.return(new Buffer(result).toString('base64')); 
    } 
  }); 
  return myFuture.wait(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good approach. `readImageFile(job.thumbUrl)` will be called with each change detection run which is quite often.

This should work

```
<img [src]="readImageFile(job.thumbUrl) | async">
```

The `| async` pipe should prevent change detection calling `readImageFile()` repeatedly.

Another approach would be to fill an array and bind to this array instead

```
getJobs() {
  this.jobs = /*code to get jobs*/.map(jobs => {
    this.images = new Array(jobs.length);
    jobs.forEach(item, idx => { 
      readImageFile(idx, item.thumbUrl);
    });
    return jobs;
  });
}
```

```
  readImageFile(idx, url) {
    if (url) {
      this.call('readImageFile', url, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log('read image file success');
          this.images[idx] = "data:image/jpg;base64," + res;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```
<div *ngFor="let job of jobs | async; let idx=index">
   <img [src]="images[idx]">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried your first suggestion and its still being called repeatedly.. Any idea why?

Comment: Does `readImageFile()` return an `Observable`? If yes, does the observable complete after the first event?

Comment: This is the readImageFile meteor method on the server. How can i find out what type it is and whether it completes? thanks

Comment: readImageFile: function(url) {
      var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
      var myFuture = new Future();

      fs.readFile(String(url), function read(error, result) {
        if(error){
          myFuture.throw(error);
        }else{
          myFuture.return(new Buffer(result).toString('base64'));
        }
      });

      return myFuture.wait();
    },

Comment: I guess when the future resolved it will call `readImageFile()` again and wait again for the returned future. You could try to return an observable that doesn't complete or just assign the result to a property as explained in my other suggestion.

Comment: I finally got this working! Its exactly the same as your second approach but inside the map function I had to add "return jobs;" at the end to get it to work. Thank you so much for your help! In my case i have two jobs, but the readImageFile callback seem to be logging to the console three times. Do you know why? Does that mean i'm reading the image more times than is necessary?

Comment: Sorry, for that. If `{}` is used an explicit `return` is required. I missed that. Glad to hear you figured it out :)

Comment: Hi Gunter, one more thing, if I add a new job to the collection it refreshes all the other jobs too. So I get this horrible pop where the images have to reload. Is there a way to avoid this? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what the problem is and what "all the other jobs" are.

Comment: Say I have three "jobs", each with a thumbnail. If I add a new job (say from the terminal) I would like that to be added reactively, which it is, but it's also refreshing the other "jobs" that were already loaded and reloads their thumbnails too (which I don't want)

Comment: Perhaps you could pass the array to `getJobs()` and `readImageFile()` where the images should be inserted instead of using a fixed one (`this.images`), then you can pass a different array for different uses and they wouldn't interfere with each other.