# Angular 2 image src as function return

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my Angular 2 application I have a list of users "Users:any" which contain the properties: name, job, age... etc. The problem is that to get the profile image  I have to get the the id of the image from the Users object, then use a web service `getImage(ImageId)`, so I have this in my html:

```
<div *ngfor="let user of users">
    <img [src]="getImage(user.profileImageId)"/>
```

In this case, I can't get the profile image displayed, I think the html is loading before the data?

Comment: Fill an array with the values and then bind to the array. Using functions in view bindings is discouraged because they are called every change detection cycle which can be quite often.

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40375935/angular2-load-binary-image-data-asynchronously-inside-ngfor/40378804#40378804

Comment: Is there a trick to wait for the data THEN display the value when data are returned ?

Comment: Yup, fill an array and run `*ngFor` on that array. `*ngFor` only renders elements when the array contains elements.

Comment: but i already have an ngFor in :

    <div *ngFor='let user of users'>
    <img src="...."/>

Comment: You can also add an `<img *ngIf="images[user.profileImageId]" [src]="images[user.profileImageId]">`

Answer (score 0):

if the webservice resolving the image url returns an Observable you have to resolve it. So to use a method to get this done you can use the async pipe:

Component:

```
getImage(id): Observable<string> {
    return http.get(url/id);
}
```

Template:

```
<img [src]="getImage(user.profileImageId) | async" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, this worked for me.

TS:

```
  getImage(id){
        return http.get(url/id);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img [src]="getImage(user.profileImageId)" />
```

Comment: Do not do this. Angular change detection will not know when the property has changed. Function getImage(id) will be called every couple of hundred milliseconds

Comment: Exactly, me too. I have to define a callback to change detection?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a trick to wait for the data THEN display the value when data
> are returned ?

Short answer: YES. you can use `async` pipe. and there are several otherways as well. Refer below for more reference.

#### The several other approaches to accomplish this are:

#### Approach 1:

Use `*ngIf` to Check for Data Availability. You can use the `*ngIf` directive to conditionally render the HTML block only if the user's data is available. This helps prevent the attempt to display images before the data is loaded. Then your html would look like this :

```
<div *ngIf="users">
  <div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <img [src]="getImage(user.profileImageId)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Approach 2:

Use the `Elvis` Operator (?.) to Safeguard against `Null` or `Undefined`. The Elvis operator (?.) can be used to safely navigate through properties in case they are null or undefined. This can help prevent errors if the user's array is not yet available. Then you html would look like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <img [src]="getImage(user?.profileImageId)" />
</div>
```

#### Approach 3:

Initialize users in the Component. Ensure that you are initializing the user's array in the component before trying to access it in the template. For example, in that case, your component.ts will look like this:

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.users = data; // Fetch users and assign to the users array
    });
  }

  getImage(imageId: string): string {      
    return this.userService.getImage(imageId).url; // Your getImage logic
  }
}
```

#### Approach 4:

Use the async Pipe. If your data is fetched asynchronously, you can use the async pipe in the template. This ensures that the template waits for the data to be resolved before rendering. In this case, ensure that your `this.userService.getUsers()` returns an `Observable` or a `Promise`.
In this case, your HTML would look like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | async">
  <img [src]="getImage(user.profileImageId)" />
</div>
```