# Unable to load img src from function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some images stored on my backend which are protected by authentication.

My application has a http interceptor set up to call my backend with a token once it's logged in.

I've tried the following code to load an image after the page has loaded but I'm hitting some issues:

html:

```
<img [src]='loadImage(example["File Name"])'/>
<figcaption>{{example['Caption']}}</figcaption>
```

ts:

```
loadImage(imgFileName)
{
  console.log("Load Image");

  let url = `${this.apiUrl}/images/${imgFileName}`;

  console.log(url);

  return this.httpClient.get(url);
}
```

Console output:

[image]

Network tab:

[image]

Comment: If you're setting the image URL, shouldn't it be just `return url;`? Doesn't make sense to pass an Ajax call to the image's src attribute.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I don't want to set the URL, I have that already - I need to load the image using Angulars http client so it will use my applications authentication token in the image request.

Comment: Sure, but it still doesn't make any sense to put the Ajax request into the src attribute. You'll have to convert the result to base64 first.

Comment: Ah okay.. I was trying the answers listed here but didn't have any luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511173/angular-2-image-src-as-function-return

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

1. If `example["File Name"]` denotes a property of an object, why would there be a space in the property name?
2. Binding a function to a property (`[src]` here) might be triggered multiple times if you aren't controlling the change detection strategy.
3. If you're trying to bind an observable (`this.http.get()` here), you need to use the `async` pipe: `[src]='loadImage(example["File Name"]) | async'`. I don't condone this statement.

The better approach would be to modify the object in the controller to add the URLs and use them directly.

Controller

```js
example = [
  { name: 'sample', Caption: 'sample', ... },
  { name: 'sample', Caption: 'sample', ... },
  { name: 'sample', Caption: 'sample', ... },
  ...
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.example.forEach(item => {
    item['url'] = this.apiUrl + '/images/' + item['name'];
  });
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let image of example">
  <img [src]="image?.url"/>
  <figcaption>{{image['Caption']}}</figcaption>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - the space is correct, it comes from a JSON key with a space in it. I can't use the URLs directly because then it bypasses my http interceptor which contains a token required to load the images.

Comment: @TomSelleck: In that case, try if this solution helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115219/6513921

Comment: This is a great explanation.